# find user exist in the table to match exact user id

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a table where the users are stored in the form of array. For example, in one blog post there are multiple user tagged

```
+ user_tagged_id + user_id + Status +
|    1, 4, 7     |   6     | Posted |
|     10, 6      |   1     | Posted |
|    11, 4, 1    |   1     | Posted |
|    1, 2        |   3     | Posted |
```

I am using a query to get users with the user id that exist in user_id column or in user_tagged_id column but with LIKE it is pulling up all the id's that match with 1 but I want to get exact number to be matched if user_id = 1 exist in user_tagged_id column it should only retun that row not all make sense

```
SELECT * FROM forums WHERE (status = 'Posted' OR status = 'Reported') 
AND (user_id = '1' OR user_tagged_id IN ('1')) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

Comment: comma separated values in a column...and I'm out...read about normalization. A database is no excel sheet.

Comment: actually I am separating because in a post more then 1 user can be tagged so that is why I am making i mean to say using this method so that multiple user can be tagged in a post

Comment: nowhere do I see a column named "status".

Comment: Multiple tables. Make multiple tables. A comma list IN A FIELD is a bad thing.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner check my post now I have added

Comment: @IncredibleHat multiple table well if I create multiple tables and user will tag 2 of his friend in a post and if I insert that data twice don't you think will be an issue?

Comment: It will not be an issue, once you start storing/using data correctly in relational tables. It'll become clear after you read about normalization as @fancyPants suggested. And I'm out too.

Comment: Easily solved using a many to many table that contains 2 columns, user id and post id both as foreign keys. You'd query to join the linking table and deal with the found data in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search in a comma separated list with a LIKE operator, you need to be aware of the different conditions that might occur:

For the examples the string that is searched for (needle) is **42**.

1. The list might contain only one element. This element might be the needle, not the needle or a string that contains the needle: It might be `42`, `5` or `142`. To only find the one you are searching for you can check, if the strings a equal: `user_tagged_id = '42'`.
2. The list might start with the needle, but contain more elements. This means, that there is a comma after the needle, but none in front of it. To make sure, that only the needle is found and not another string that ends or starts on the needle -- like `12342` or `425` -- you need to include the successive comma to your condition, but not any precede sign: `user_tagged_id LIKE CONCAT('42', ',%')`.
3. The list might contain the needle. To make sure that no string is found that starts or ends with the needle -- like `12342` or `425` --, both, the preceding and successive comma, need to be added to the LIKE condition: `user_tagged_id LIKE CONCAT('%, ', '42', ',%')`
4. The list might end with the needle. To make sure that no string is found that ends on the needle -- like `3842` -- the preceding comma needs to be part of the LIKE condition: `user_tagged_id LIKE CONCAT('%, ', '42')`

To filter your list for specific ids you need to add all four conditions as a disjunction.

Since this is very loading intensive i would suggest you to rather create a new table that holds the user taggings and `JOIN` it in your query.